# MongoDb : How to set IndexOptions background true for compound indexes in Java

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-java, mongodb-indexes

For Single Field indexes in mongodb we can set the IndexOptions as below

```
collection.createIndex(
            Indexes.ascending(actualIndexFieldName), new IndexOptions().background(true));
```

But not sure how to set the IndexOptions for a compound index in java.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can.

[Refer](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html)

```
java.lang.String createIndex(Bson keys,
                             IndexOptions indexOptions)
Create an index with the given keys and options.
Parameters:
keys - an object describing the index key(s), which may not be null.
indexOptions - the options for the index
```

To Use `Indexes`

`public static Bson compoundIndex(java.util.List<? extends Bson> indexes)`

[Refer](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/Indexes.html#compoundIndex-java.util.List-)

```
ArrayList<Document> indexes = new ArrayList<Document>();
indexes.add(Indexes.descending("stars")); 
indexes.add(Indexes.ascending("name"));
collection.createIndex(indexes, indexOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks .. but how can i create the compound index with index options , if am creating this way.   collection.createIndex(Indexes.compoundIndex(Indexes.descending("stars"), Indexes.ascending("name")));

Comment: i think there is a small correction.. the syntax will be like this       collection.createIndex(Indexes.compoundIndex(indexes), new IndexOptions().background(true)); and the list is not Document , it must be a Bson list       List<Bson> indexes = new ArrayList<Bson>();

Comment: I will check that Abhi. I see list element extends Bson. Document extends Bson. So should work. I ll check and correct it. Thanks for letting us know